Как в FFMPEG получить из системы установленные энкодеры аудио и видео, которые точно заработаю на "данной" машине?
понадобилось сделать небольшую обёртку для ffmpeg на delphi
но появилась проблема, если получить список энкодеров из ffmpeg то выбрав какой либо энкодер не факт что он заработает!
т.е. у меня на компе есть NVIDIA видяха и на ней чудесно работает NVENC, а на соседнем компе стоит Radeon и соответственно этот энкодер работать не будет (ему там работать не начем - железа нет подходящего)
по этому и появился вопрос: подскажите как получить из системы установленные энкодеры аудио и видео, которые точно заработаю на "данной" машине (как на delphi/pascal получить список установленных в системе энкодеров?)
P.S. то что с собой тащит ffmpeg не факт что сможет работать на любом железе

Думаю в вашем случае нужно еще проверять работоспособность энкодеров скриптом (вероятно пытаясь их применить) ffmpeg -encoders будет мало

@DaniilLoban вот у меня пока тоже создалось такое впечатление, что из всех представленных в -encoders проверить их работоспособность можно только запустив на небольшом файлике куда то в память и если не будет ошибки, тогда его можно оставить в списке

Если вдруг видеокарт несколько из разных поколений, то к этому ещё придётся добавить веселье с поиском конкретной видеокарты, на которой сможет заработать интересующий кодек
